# Trying to make this CMD line work

Tags: cmd, command

So I created a context menu in the registry

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > * > shell > copy > commmand > cmd /c dir "%1" /b /a:-d /o:n | clip
```

This copies the file name when I right click on a file, yet I want to add it so it will copy some text before the file name.

so it would be like `db.yetteh.co.uk/%1 %1` being the filename.

```
cmd /c echo db.yetteh.co.uk & dir "%1" /b /a:-d /o:n | clip
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd /c (ECHO db.yetteh.co.uk&dir /b /a:-d /o:n "%~1")|clip
```

should work for you.